# Файловая система для NAND Flash под FreeRTOS

Tags: файловая-система, embedded, flash-память, freertos

В моем embedded проекте на базе LPC3250 под управлением FreeRTOS появилась необходимость вести энергонезависимый лог. Из доступной энергонезависимой памяти имеется NAND flash. Но основной проблемой является реализация алгоритма управления памятью с учетом контроля битых секторов, и необходимости оперативно записывать данные. Так как nand контроллер в ЦПУ не позволяет работать в режиме случайной адресации и писать можно только страницами по 2кБ, а это объем ~10 минут лога, при выключении питания или железном перезапуске ЦПУ эти последние 10 минут могут быть утеряны.

Подскажите пожалуйста файловые системы подходящие для этого.

Или может литературу о подходах к реализации подобных задач.

Comment: Похоже, что в такой постановке задача не может быть решена выбором подходящей файловой системы. Все равно последние 10 минут будут потеряны. Ну, или писать данные по мере появления. Но за это придется расплачиваться уменьшением ресурса flash.

Comment: Кстати, вполне возможно, что если писать во flash одно и то же, то контроллер не будет перезаписывать информацию. И тогда потери ресурса flash не будет.

Comment: А проверить это очень просто. Надо пожертвовать одним контроллером и зациклить на нем запись одной и той же информации. Если после миллиона-двух записей flash не умрет, значит физической перезаписи не производится.

Comment: pepsicoca1, вы были правы микросхема не инициирует цикл записи для адресов  данные в которых не отличающихся по значению от уже сохраненных. Поэтому можно дописывать данные в страницы не уменьшая их ресурса. Спасибо.

Comment: Это в описании написано? Я бы все равно проверил. Зациклил бы на порядок больше записей одинаковой информации, чем гарантировано, и поглядел, не умрет ли flash.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, скажите, вы пробовали открывать документацию на какую-нибудь микросхему NAND ? Там вполне подробно описано, в каких случаях будет происходить перезапись. Или вообще полистать какие-нибудь популярные статьи по технологии флеш, чтобы понимать отличия терминов "erase" и "write" в данном конкретном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов у Вас 2:

Нулевой пункт (обязательный в любом случае)/ Разобраться, что такое NAND, что такое "запись" и какие на самом деле минимальные объемы записи и стирания могут быть.

1. Взять какую-то готовую библиотеку, которая делает преобразование больших и неудобных блоков NAND в маленькие сектора с произвольным доступом на запись. Варианты из бесплатных - https://os.mbed.com/blog/entry/littlefs-high-integrity-embedded-fs/ или https://github.com/rickyzheng/uffs . Плюсы - удобная ФС (можно хранить любые данные, не только логи), защита от badblock'ов (а они, согласно документации производителя, могут быть).
2. Альтернатива - если нужен только журнал, просто писать по кругу. Плюсы - простота реализации. Минусы - нарушение требований производителя NAND (в большинстве случаев указывают, что в стёртую страницу можно писать только один раз; у кого-то видел строчку "partial write - до 4 раз"), отсутствие ECC, вероятно, отсутствие обработки bad block'ов. Но практика показывает, что изделия с таким подходом тоже вполне жизнеспособны - у нас выпущено несколько тысяч штук железок, по гарантии с проблемой "что-то случилось с NAND" вернулось только несколько штук.

Comment: Только уточните, что говоря про "писать один раз" и "partial write" под страницей обычно понимают 256 байт (именно этот объем обычно пишут в буфер микросхемы, а затем дают команду `записать на носитель`), а стирают блоками по 4K (можно группой по 64K или флешку целиком).  И ничто не мешает писать в другие еще не записанные страницы (по 256 байт) в пределах одного и того же блока в произвольном порядке (адрес же в контроллере вы задаете?). И еще, один и тот же блок можно стирать и перезаписывать много раз.

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое "обычная микросхема". В "обычной" гигабитной Macronix ( [даташит](http://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/6855/MX30LF1G18AC,%203V,%201Gb,%20v1.2.pdf) ) тысяча блоков по 64 страницы по 2кбайта (точнее, по 2112 байт) каждая.

Возможно, вы путаете с NOR flash, там как раз "обычный размер" страницы 256 байт.

Comment: Похоже, вы правы и я написал про NOR (через год всех деталей уже не помню, надо будет уточнить ...)

Comment: Alexey Esaulenko, спасибо за ответ. Проект https://github.com/rickyzheng/uffs -очень интересный вариант. По первой оценке выглядит простым для портирования на разные платформы.

Comment: uffs довольно много памяти хочет (как, впрочем, и большинство других подобных библиотек). Какая магия внутри mbed'овской библиотеки, я не разбирался, сейчас вопрос мне не очень актуален.

Comment: `NAND` — способ организации гейтов с точки зрения их логической функции, а именно здесь `not AND`. То, о чём вы говорите в *нулевом пункте*, немного ортогонально прочему.